# Como fazer loop com regex em javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, loop

Olá pessoal tudo bem? Estou quebrando a cabeça na seguinte questão:

Tenho um conjunto de string:

```
var teste = blabla 555..  999
```

Tenho duplo espaço em branco entre os dígitos e fiz o regex:

```
var str = teste.replace(/\s{2,}/g, '.');
```

O problema que ele irá substituir os dois espaços por apenas um ponto ".", eu queria fazer um loop com o seguinte algoritmo:

1. Encontrei 2 espaços em branco
2. Substitui por dois pontos "."
3. Ficaria assim: teste = blabla 555....999

Alguma luz, caminho das pedras?

Comment: Tente fazer `/\s{1}/g`, e substitua cada espaço por um ponto, usando um while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sou um guru em JavaScript, então, qualquer erro é só dizer.

```
function times(str, n){
    var step = str;
    for (var y = 1; y < n; y++){
       str = str.concat(step);
    }
    return str;
}

test = "a b  d"
test = test.replace(/\s{2,}/g, function(match) {
    return times(".", match.length);
});

>>> a b..d
```

Teste: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmohesfd/10/)

Encontra sequências de espaços `n ≥ 2` e faz o devido `replace` por `'.' * n`.

Comment: Olá dxhj, funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado. Vou fazer o teste de mesa para entender o algoritmo. Sempre gosto de saber como funcionam as coisas.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi, seu problema.

Mas se entendi você quer procurar em uma determinada frase dois espaços em branco seguidos e substitui-los por ".."? Certo?

Se assim for é só você trocar o `replace` assim:

```
// procura por 2 espaços em branco da frase e substitui por ".."
var str = teste.replace(/\s{2,}/g, '..');
```

[Exemplo online.](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/3ptc958k/)

Confira se era isso que você necessitava?

Comment: Olá Fernando, a solução do dxhj funcionou. Agradeço sua resposta. Abraços.